# How to quote link with underscores in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, url

I tried package url.
So, I do

```
@manual {Papaya,
   author = {Sapir, Marina},
   title = {Papaya Orchard: Comedy in one act},
   url = {https://www.academia.edu/35254962/_Papaya_Orchard_Comedy_in_one_act}, 
}
```

And it just ignores url:  there is no url in bibliography in the pdf file for this reference. If I use
note= {}  instead of url = {}
I get error messages for underscores.
Is there a way to have url with underscores in bibliography?

Comment: If and how the `url` field is displayed in the bibliography depends on the bibliography style you use and possible also on URL-related packages you load in your preamble. We can only give you good advice if you share your bibliography setup with us in a short, yet compilable example document (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: @moewe I figured out how to do it and posted the answer.

Comment: In general I would recommend not (LaTeX-)escaping any characters in URLs and using the package `url` instead (if and how easy that is depends on your bibliography setup), but if you found another way ...

Answer (score 1):

If the bibliography style you employ doesn't recognize the field name `url`, you should encase the entire URL string in a `\url{...}` wrapper and place the `\url{...}` in a `note` field. And, load the `xurl` package so that the contents of `\url{...}` can be easily broken across two or more lines.

Do *not* escape any `_` (underscore) characters and other TeX-special characters in the URL string unless you (a) are prepared and willing to create massively overfull or underfull lines in the bibliographic entries and (b) don't care about being nice to your readers by making the URL into a clickable hyperlink to the source on the Internet.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@manual {Papaya,
   author = {Sapir, Marina},
   title = {Papaya Orchard: Comedy in one act},
   note = {\url{https://www.academia.edu/35254962/_Papaya_Orchard_Comedy_in_one_act}}, 
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{plain} % choose a suitable bib style
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xurl} % for '\url' macro
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % to make URL strings "clickable"

\begin{document}
\cite{Papaya}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a perfect solution. It works.

Comment: This happens if I don't scape the characters. `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In the link, I use `{\_}` (backslash underscore in curly brackets instead of underscore).
I do not need the package `url`. And I use `note ={}` to quote.
It looks like this:

```
{\_}Papaya{\_}Orchard{\_}Comedy{\_}in{\_}one{\_}act}
```

Comment: For some reason, it does not work for me. The curly brackets are being printed into the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use the `hyperref` package, and either put the URL into a `howpublished` tag of use a `note` with `'url{...}`.